# Vim, reopen last closed window, that was in split

Tags: vim, split

Is it possible to reopen closed window in vim, that was in split?

Something like ctrl+shift+t with browser tabs?

Comment: This won't answer your question, but there is a `:ls` command to list all buffers, even closed ones. You can find your buffer there and use `:b 15` to open buffer 15 in the current window.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that, but would be awesome to just hit some keys combination and reopen last closed window.

Comment: Note: C-S-t is reopen last closed tab in Chrome

Comment: @sehe - Or more of them at once, depending.

Comment: What about: <C-w>v<C-6> ?
It first opens the current buffer in a vertical split and then switches to the previous buffer.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`:vs#` will split current window vertically and open the alternate file.
It's so simple that you don't need to bind it to key.

Comment: oh this is pretty nice. I may not work for people using `rails.vim` or similar plugin because the hook into vim to give you specific files as alternate

Comment: actually you don't even need the `#`.

Comment: @JohnNguyen The `#` is defintely needed, otherwise the same file as shown in the current buffer will be opened in the split buffer.

Comment: Where is the `#` symbol documented in the vim manual? `:help #` only shows the search-under-cursor one

Comment: @SOFe `:help cmdline-special`

Answer (score 16):

Nice question! I was thinking to something like the following:

```
nmap <c-s-t> :vs<bar>:b#<CR>
```

It should work as you want.

Comment: This technically opens the alternate buffer, which is not always the same like the last closed buffer.

Comment: Yes I know... but I can't think a better way to do somthing like that. I'm thinking about it

Comment: mmm It doesn't readily work on my vim (I get `buffer 4 does not exist`). I don't actually know what b# does, though

Comment: Great! It works. Now I just need second namp to open it in sp. Like nmap <c-s-s> :sp<bar>:b#<CR>. Or maybe there is a way to choose the best split to the current layout of windows?

Comment: @sehe See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching . I can't find a link to official doc for :b#. By the way, I confess I'm surprised that you didn't already do that. Reading your answers about Vim I got the feeling you know everything about it :)

Comment: @lucapette: roughly :) There are some areas that I never quite feel the need for. Really, `:buf main` is enough to ge into the `main.cpp` buffer (without having to track all kinds of magic buffer numbers). Also, I just did a quick test and reported back, without _thinking_ for lack of time

Comment: I really wanted a feature in ViM to undo the last step again ... including GUI stuff and more.

Answer (score 2):

No need for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>:

```
nmap <c-t> :vs<bar>:b#<CR>
```

In conjunction with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> the characters are handled equally by vim, capitalized or not.

Actually also in the answer before, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> should both work.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this to work by using [`bufmru.vim`](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2346)!

The following command, `:ReopenLastTab`, will re-split the last-open buffer:

```
command ReopenLastTab execute "vsplit" bufname(g:bufmru_bnrs[1])
```

I installed bufmru using `Vundle`, as below, but of course you can install it any way you like.

```
#.vimrc

" Install bufmru with Vundle
Plugin 'vim-scripts/bufmru.vim'

let g:bufmru_switchkey = "<c-t>"  " I never use this: the default is Space, but I don't need to use it so set it to something I don't care about.
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone need something more generic I made this function.

Just place it in your .vimrc

```
" open last closed buffer
function! OpenLastClosed()
    let last_buf = bufname('#')

    if empty(last_buf)
        echo "No recently closed buffer found"
        return
    endif
    let result = input("Open ". last_buf . " in (n)ormal (v)split, (t)ab or (s)plit ? (n/v/t/s) : ")
    if empty(result) || (result !=# 'v' && result !=# 't' && result !=# 's' && result !=# 'n')
        return
    endif
    if result ==# 't'
        execute 'tabnew'
    elseif result ==# 'v'
        execute "vsplit"
    elseif result ==# 's'
        execute "split"
    endif
    execute 'b ' . last_buf
endfunction

nnoremap <C-t> :call OpenLastClosed() <CR>
```

Call it with `Ctrl+t` and then select where you want to open that file.